# ASP.NET beginners quetions

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create my first web application using ASP.NET. I've created new sample ASP.NET project application.

First of all I want to understand how do I switch from local App_Data file to proper database and how whole authentication process is working.

1. Db switch. What I did is, attached current example of .mdf file through SQL management studio on a server. But I am not sure how should I modify my connection string. Could you help me please?

   connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
2. Could you please explain how authentication is working? Say after user enter its credentials and hits enter, somewhere in a code it has to validate username and password, but I can't find where it happens.

Lets say my user A is Moderator and user B is simple user. How should I detect which one it is? How do I display extra features for user A, since he is a Moderato?

Comment: Too broad. I think you have to read some books first ;).

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I think broad questions are ok, as long as the op is willing to accept broad answers.

Comment: @dbaseman, what about "I don't know ASP.NET, can you teach me please!!!"? ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the connection string, the best option is to use Visual Studio.  Go to Data -> Add New Data Source and follow the UI.  Failing that, [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/) is a great reference.
2. There are different types of authentication in ASP.net, but given that you want to implement roles (user/moderator), Forms Authentication is probably a good choice.  There are lots of resources on how to set this up, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240) for example.
3. The final step is to implement [roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx) so that your application knows who is a user, and who's a moderator.  Once you have this configured correctly, your application can use simple logic like *if (User.IsInRole("moderator"))* ...

Answer (score 1):

1.) connection string varies by the used database and the actual server settings. Consult this with your hosting provider if you can't figure it by yourself

2.) this depends on the actual implementation. Basic idea looks like this:

Provide user a login form. User sends back the form with filled in credentials. On the server there's a function, that compares these credentials to those stored in persistence medium (like a db) and if they match, the user is authenticated. If they don't match, you get an error.